# Capturing setOnClickListener() and setOnFocusChangeListener()

Tags: android

I'm writing an API for Android and I need to know when the developer using the API calls `View.setOnClickListener()` and `View.setOnFocusChangeListener()`. I don't want to override either because that would mean to extend `View` and I don't want to force the developer to use my subclass -basically because he wouldn't be able to use the Android GUI editor for Eclipse-.

I tried to override `Activity.dispatchTouchEvent()` but then I cannot capture movements done with keypad/virtual keyboard.

Any ideas or guidelines on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using both `Activity.dispatchTouchEvent()` and `Activity.dispatchKeyEvent()` is the only way of doing this. You have to keep track of the view that had focus previously (so you can know when `onFocusChange()` is triggered). The `onClick()` can be detected using `MotionEvent` action and the view ID.